# Dealing with noisy points

Tags: graphing-functions, finance, noise

The following picture represents a graph with price over time. I am a mathematical student, but also a trader. I want to create a function which could localize the good entry and exit points for sale and buy stocks. However, I am struggling with the noisy data. Simply using $p_t > p_{t+k}$ to determine the direction of the price would introduce unmanageable amount of noise, since the smallest change would register as an upward or downward movement. The green circle on the picture shows an unacceptable noise, while the pink circle is an acceptable noise and induce a new exit and entry point.

[image: Prive over Time Graph]

How could I deal with noisy points? I want to set a point of entry and exit when the initial price has increased by a certain percentage, but I need to tell my function not to consider a drop of a certain percentage (noise). If the drop reaches that percentage and there is a sufficient increase in the initial price, then I will an exit point.

Some people explain it is possible to set up a threshold. How could we explain that mathematically in that context?

### UPDATE

We want to predict the direction towards which the price will change.
The term price is used to refer to the mid-price of a
stock, which is defined as the mean between the best bid price and
best ask price at time $t$: $$p_t =
\frac{p_a^{(1)}(t)+p_b^{(1)}(t)}{2}$$

This is a virtual value for the price since no order can happen at
that exact price, but predicting its upwards or downwards movement
provides a good estimate of the price of the future orders. A set of
discrete choices must be constructed from our data to use as targets
for our classification model. Simply using $p_t > p_{t+k}$ to
determine the direction of the mid-price would introduce unmanageably
amount of noise, since the smallest change would be registered as an
upward or downward movement.

In order to filter the noise, I think it is good to following smoothed approach. First, the mean of the previous $k$ mid-prices, denoted by $m_b$, and the mean of the next $k$ mid-prices, denoted by $m_a$, are defined as: $$m_a(t) = \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^{k} p_{t-i}$$ $$m_b(t) = \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=0}^{k} p_{t+i}$$

A label $l_t$ that express the direction of price movement at time $t$
is extracted by comparing the previously defined quantities ($m_b$ and
$m_a$):

$$ l_t =   \begin{cases}
     1,      & m_b(t) > m_a(t) (1+α)\\
     -1,  & m_b(t) < m_a(t) (1-α) \\
     0,    & \text{otherwise}   \end{cases} $$

where the threshold $α$ is set as the least amount of change in price
that must occur for it to be considered upward or downward. If the
price does not exceed this limit, the sample will be considered to
belong to the stationary class. Therefore, the resulting label
expresses the current trend we wish to predict. Note that this process
is applied for every time step in our data.

Is it a good way to handle the noise? I could take into account a threshold $\alpha=0.05$ and an horizon $k=10$. A big advantage of using the mean of surrounding prices is that we can prevent drastic drops. In other words, if there was a drastic drop a time $t$, then we can set up an exit point at a time $t'$, where $t'<t$, in order to establish a certain security. To not be caught in a descent too fast.

Comment: IMO, in stock exchange data, there is no border between signal and noise. Also, the decisions taken on the example (green vs. pink) seem pretty arbitrary and are not convincing.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to set a threshold.  The drop has to be more than some percentage to accept it.  It is easy (after the fact) to mark the entry points but how do you know at that time that it is a bottom?  Similarly, it is easy (after the fact) to mark the exit points, but how do you know it is a top in real time?  If you can do that the drops in the green circles should be exploited as well unless your commission level is too high to make those uneconomic.

You have drawn a function that is in a particular class, almost piecewise linear but with perturbations that show your point.  Your perturbations are on only two scales.  I suspect that if you look at the historical record you will find many different behaviors.  You will find times when there is no overall trend.  It is true, those times you may not care whether you are in or out of the market.

Comment: The draw was just a representation of my thoughts. Could you explain mathematically what you mean by setting a threshold? I want to set a point of entry and exit when the initial price has increased by a certain **minimal** percentage, but I need to tell my function not to consider a drop of a certain percentage (noise).

Comment: You are restating my point.  You would just say if the current price is less than some factor $k$ times the previous peak you consider it, while if it is withing $k$ of the previous peak you ignore it.  I have seen writers promote $k=0,8$ and other values.  If it has dropped by a factor $k$ why do you think it won't keep dropping?  But don't focus on whether the drops are large enough, focus on how you find the peaks and bottoms.  You want all the peaks and bottoms that are far enough apart to cover your commission and taxes.  Finding them is hard in real time, easy in retrospect.

Comment: I would very appreciate if you could explain that with rigorous mathematical symbolics (with example if possible).

Comment: I was presuming that the drop in the purple circle was greater than $k$ and the drops in the green circles were less than $k$.  You are poking at what is called "technical analysis" in the financial world.  The idea is that certain patterns in historical movements forecast future movements.  If you can find such patterns you can make a fortune, even if you lose a lot of the time but on average you gain.  There are lots of people trying to find such patterns.  You are then betting that the patterns from the past will be reproduced in the future.

Comment: Each of your entries is a bottom.  How do you find one in real time?  You don't put a scale on your graph but lets assume the drop in the green circles is less than $20\%$ while the drop in purple is greater than $20\%$.  The climb from the bottom on the day in question is tiny by comparison.  How do you tell that climb from noise?  That is a **much** better question than the one you asked.

Comment: I have updated my question. Is it what you mean by a threshold?

Comment: I was focused on the size of the overall drop, because that seemed the difference between the green and purple events.  Your sort of filtering is fine if there is a characteristic time scale to the noise that is different from the time scale of the signal.  I am not convinced that exists in the stock market.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the time scale of the signal'?

Comment: You have drawn a graph with lots of little zigs and zags, which you are calling noise.  Those might be durations of a few minutes.  You also have big zigs and zags which you are calling signal with durations that might be a few days.  Those are the time scales I am talking about.  There is a whole literature on filtering that works on this distinction.   If you look at real data you won't find a nice separation like that.